# Намалюватися чи нанести макіяж? Як правильно?

Tags: вживання-слів, значення-слів

В промо-ролику [Едем](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nZOESr6WVBE) звучить така фраза: *"Важко дійти до роботи, намалюватись..."* В ролику слово ***"намалюватися"*** означає нанесення косметики.

В СУМ-11 подано визначення

> **[НАМАЛЮВАТИСЯ](http://sum.in.ua/s/namaljuvatysja)**  ююся, юєшся, розм. Док. до малюватися. *Шміло й
>   собі ж вліпив котячий, хитрий погляд в парубка. Зразу на його лиці
>   намалювався якийсь неспокій* (Іван Франко, I, 1955, 160).

На мою, думку правильно було б сказати ***"робити макіяж"*** тим паче що в СУМ-20 присутне слово ***"макіяж"***.

> **[МАКІЯ́Ж](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=154763&page=1551)**, у, ч. Нанесення на шкіру обличчя декоративної косметики
>   для прикрашання, а також приховування недоліків. *– Що мені треба
>   зробити? – спокійно спитала я. – Постригтися. Відмовитись від макіяжу.
>   Змінити стиль одягу* (Любко Дереш); *Третина жінок, які взяли участь в
>   опитуванні, заявили, що хотіли б скоротити час, який вони витрачають
>   на макіяж* (із журн.).

***Чи правильно вживати слово "намалюватися" в значені "нанесення макіяжу"? Як правильно "робити чи наносити макіяж"?***

Comment: Коли вам треба *розмовний* стиль - "намалюватися". Коли більш формальний - "нанести макіяж".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хоч семантично ці слова повязані, але в цьому випадку контекстуально варто вживати **нафарбуватися**, бо мова йде не про створення малюнка на обличчі, а про нанесення косметичних фарб - помади, тонального засобу тощо.

> ФАРБУВА́ТИСЯ, уюся, уєшся, недок.
>
> 1. Покриватися або просочуватися фарбою.
> 2. Фарбувати собі волосся, обличчя, губи; малюватися.

[СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/farbuvatysja)

**Наносити макіяж**, звісно, також вірно.